# Sagemaker - build your own docker container from a poetry vm

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am learning sagemaker and would like to build my own Docker container from my code. I looked at examples here: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit, but I have no experience with Docker and really struggle to understand what I need to do so build my docker container properly.

My Python project structure looks like this

```
myproject
  -src
    - module1
      - ...py
      - ...py
    - module2
      - ...py
    - train.py
  -poetry.lock
  -pyproject.toml
```

Firstly, I am not sure how to write a basic script to package the whole project into a docker container.

Secondly, assuming I have the answer to question 1 above, and following the instructions from the link above that says I should add the following content to my Dockerfile, I don't know how I should adapt the line **'COPY train.py /opt/ml/code/train.py'** because my project has nested folders and is not a single flat .py file.

```
FROM yourbaseimage:tag

# install the SageMaker Training Toolkit 
RUN pip3 install sagemaker-training

# copy the training script inside the container
COPY train.py /opt/ml/code/train.py

# define train.py as the script entry point
ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM train.py
```

Comment: Set your working directory to where your scripts are located, this will allow for the other scripts to be picked up as well. Hosting example: https://github.com/RamVegiraju/SageMaker-Deployment/tree/master/RealTime/BYOC/PreTrained-Examples/SpacyNER?source=post_page-----37211d8412f4--------------------------------